# Environment.GetFolderPath for LocalApplicationData returns empty string

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've encountered a strange bug: when my software is being started as another user using CreateProcessAsUser API Environment.GetFolderPath static method returns empty string for LocalApplicationData special folder. This bug doesn't occur all the time, and can't really figure out the exact situation when it happens and why it happens. Could you tell me why this thing may happen and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**: It seems that it was a problem in legacy code that calls CreateProcessAsUser. The code didn't create environment block for the new process, I've added the calls to CreateEnvironmentBlock and DestroyEnvironmentBlock API and the problem doesn't appear anymore. Don't really know if it is the right solution, but it seems to work. What do you think?

Comment: Can you please post an example of your code, where you may even think its happening etc..

Answer (score 0):

maybe the folder doesn't exist. if that folder physically exists on the computer Environment.GetFolderPath has value; otherwise,returns an empty string ("").

regards,

Answer (score 0):

By design, LocalApplicationData stays on the local machine and does not roam. ApplicationData does roam for example if the user logs onto the domain from a different computer it will be synced. So LocalApplicationData should not be user specific. Is your software run on the same machine every time? It may be helpful to check the ApplicationData path behavior?